# Reading a file and output selected data

Tags: c++11, codeblocks, ifstream

I'm trying to read data and output only selected data from a CSV file(Date, time and S(speed). My program is able to run but it loops in a weird way. Line 1, than Line 1 and 2, than Line 1,2 and 3 and so on and so forth. The final record that is shown in the program is also incorrect(0/3/2016 23:50). Need some guidance to rectify this problem.

Sample data in notepad format below. It contains thousands of line but only pick the last 3 lines to illustrate my problem. Ignore the "Line" below, it's just to tell you which line is in excel format. Line 1 is the header which i ignore, follow by the data.

Line 1:WAST,DP,Dta,Dts,EV,QFE,QFF,QNH,RF,RH,S,SR,ST1,ST2,ST3,ST4,Sx,T

Line 2: **31/03/2016 23:30**,11.4,257,11,0,1012.9,1016.4,1016.5,0,63.5,**5**,13,26.4,25.8,25.6,26.1,7,18.48

Line 3: **31/03/2016 23:40**,11.4,250,15,0,1012.9,1016.4,1016.5,0,64.7,**5**,10,26.4,25.8,25.6,26.1,6,18.19

Line 4:**31/03/2016 23:50**,11.4,243,5,0,1012.7,1016.2,1016.3,0,65.8,**3**,11,26.3,25.8,25.6,26.1,5,17.95

### Current Output:

31/3/2016 23:30 
Speed: 5

31/3/2016 23:30 
Speed: 5

31/3/2016 23:40 
Speed: 5

31/3/2016 23:30 
Speed: 5

31/3/2016 23:40
Speed: 5

31/3/2016 23:50
Speed: 3

31/3/2016 23:30
Speed: 5

31/3/2016 23:40
Speed: 5

31/3/2016 23:50
Speed: 3

0/3/2016 23:50
Speed: 3

Max Speed: 5

Done!

### Intended Output

31/3/2016 23:30
Speed: 5

31/3/2016 23:40
Speed: 5

31/3/2016 23:50
Speed: 3

Max Speed: 5

Done!

```
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
Date d;
Time t;
float speed;
}
WindLogType;

//declare speed max function
ostream & operator <<(ostream &osObject, const WindLogType & w1);
istream & operator >>(istream &input, WindLogType &w1);

int main()
{
string filename;
ifstream input;

filename = "Data.csv";

input.open(filename.c_str());
input.ignore(500,'\n');

Vector<WindLogType> windlog;

string line,line2, readDay, readMonth, readYear, readHour, readMinute;
float sp;


while(!input.eof())
{

    getline(input,readDay,'/');
    getline(input,readMonth,'/');
    getline(input,readYear,' ');

    getline(input,readHour,':');
    getline(input,readMinute,',');


int day1 =atoi(readDay.c_str());
int month1=atoi(readMonth.c_str());
int year1=atoi(readYear.c_str());
int hour1=atoi(readHour.c_str());
int minute1=atoi(readMinute.c_str());

float s1;

for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
    input>>s1;
    input.ignore(50,',');
}

WindLogType T1;//create a record
T1.d.setDate(day1,month1,year1);
T1.t.setTime(hour1,minute1);
T1.speed = s1;

windlog.push_back(T1);//push inside vector
windlog.print();

getline(input,line2,'\n');
}
float maxSpeed;
WindLogType H1;
H1=windlog.at(0);
maxSpeed=H1.speed;

for(int i=0;i<windlog.size();i++)
{
    if(windlog.at(i).speed>maxSpeed)
    {
        maxSpeed=windlog.at(i).speed;
    }
}
cout<<"Max Speed: "<<maxSpeed<<endl;

cout<<"Done!"<<endl;


return 0;
}

ostream & operator <<(ostream &osObject, const WindLogType &w1)
{
osObject<<w1.d<<w1.t<<endl<<"Speed: "<<w1.speed;
return osObject;
}

istream &operator >>(istream & input, WindLogType &w1)
{
input>>w1.d>>w1.t>>w1.speed;
return input;
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, remember that class and structure names are also type-names. So doing `struct WindLogType { ... };` is enough to introduce `WindLogType` as a type. No need for `typedef`.

Comment: I also suggest you read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). As well as [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You call `windlog.print();` in every iteration of the loop, for every line. Each time, it prints the whole list accumulated so far. You probably want to call it once, at the end after all data has been processed.